# Images not displaying in Laravel 4 Framework

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using the Laravel 4 Framework and I am trying to have some images appear on my page.  I have two different cases.  One, I am using an image as a background in a CSS file.  The image is in a folder 'images', inside a folder 'assets', inside the public folder.  The CSS of note is this:

```
.banner-image{background:transparent url('/assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;background-size:cover; height:800px; min-width: 1200px;}
```

In the view, I call the CSS by using: `<div class="banner-image"></div>`

On the page, div is appear as white space (takes up the allotted pixels), but the image is not showing.

In the same view, I am calling another image, using the html:

```
<img src="/assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png">
```

However, the image is appearing as a broken link.  Is there another style I have to use to call images in Laravel 4?  Thank you for your help with these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the CSS, make sure the image is in a folder called **assets, at the same level as the CSS file**. And then try this:

```
.banner-image
{
  background: url('assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg');
}
```

In your View, try:

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}">
```

Assuming you have the assets folder in your public directory.

Comment: For the CSS, the image is still appearing as blank...  I have the assets folder within the public folder.  Inside the assets folder, I have the style.css file inside a "CSS" folder, and the image inside a "images" folder.

Comment: Then you need to go back a step and then enter the images folder:      url('../images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg')

Answer (score 3):

try in your View
{{HTML::image('images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}

Answer (score 1):

Another way, in a view file

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png')}}" />
```

**fanssignupsplash.png** image needs to be available at `http://example.com/assets/images/fanssignupsplash.png`